# Change color of radius of point in flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a situation in flot where I want the points to be 1 pixel GREEN dots. To do this I'm using the following settings:

```
points: {
 show: true,
 radius: 1,
 lineWidth: 0
},
colors:["#00FF00"]
```

This works fine with the only problem being that 'colors' changes the line around the radius, which for me is non-existent, and I want to change the color of the actual radius of the data point. As it is right now I'm stuck with default white. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
points: {
 show: true,
 radius: 1,
 lineWidth: 0,
 fillColor: '#00FF00'
}
```